# Autodienstangebote Einlagerung

Tags: meaning

Ich habe einen Brief von meiner Autoversicherung bekommen, wo Einlagerung ab 30.-€ angeboten wird. Die Bedeutung im Duden ist:

> 1.- das Einlagern (1)
>
> 2.-  a) das Sicheinlagern b) etwas in einer anderen Materie Abgelagertes

und 
das Einlagern

> 1.- zur Aufbewahrung, Lagerung in einen dafür geeigneten Raum bringen
>
> 2.- sich in einer anderen Materie festsetzen, ablagern

Es fällt mir schwer zu verstehen, was Einlagerung mit Auto zu tun hat.

Comment: Was mich etwas wundert ist, dass das Angebot von Deiner Kfz-Versicherung kommt. Sind die 30.-€ monatlich oder jährlich? Wenn 30.-€ monatlich gemeint sind, könnte eventuell auch ein Garagenstellplatz gemeint sein, dann spricht man aber normalerweise nicht von Einlagerung. Es sei denn, es handelt sich bei dem Fahrzeug um z.B. einen Oldtimer, der im Winter dauerhaft in der Garage stehen soll.

Comment: Gibt es da mehr Kontext? Wollen sie Dich, Dein Auto, die Autoreifen, den Vertrag einlagern? 30€ pauschal, pro Tag, pro Jahr? Ist das Werbung, die dem Versicherungsschreiben beilag? Handelt es sich vielleicht um die Schweiz oder Österreich?

Comment: _@birdman_ Wärst Du bitte so freundlich die offenen Fragen die hier gestellt wurden zu Beantworten. Andernfalls ist es schwierig eine eindeutige Antwort zu geben.

Comment: Ist dies hier wirklich der richtige Platz, falsche, schräge oder ungeschickte Wortwahl von Werbetreibenden aufzuklären?

Comment: Einlagerung bedeutet, dass die Werkstatt halt die Reifen für das Season. Bis die Reifen wieder gewechselt werden sollen.

Comment: @birdman Es ist trotzdem noch etwas unklar, warum Dir das Deine Kfz-Versicherung anbietet?

Comment: Einfach Werbung, die ich mit Sonderabat bekommen habe, weil ich die Versicherung habe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Es fällt mir schwer zu verstehen, was Einlagerung mit Auto zu tun hat.

In der Regel ist damit die Einlagerung der Sommer- bzw. Winterreifen gemeint.

In diesem Fall würde also die folgende Bedeutung zutreffen:

> > 1.- zur Aufbewahrung, Lagerung in einen dafür geeigneten Raum bringen

Comment: Durch eine Versicherung? Ich habe nicht so viele Autos, aber das kommt mir merkwürdig vor.

Comment: @userunknown Ja, mir auch. Daher mein [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/56150/autodienstangebote-einlagerung/56151?noredirect=1#comment137964_56150).

Comment: Mh. Antworten, obwohl man für das Schließen der Frage als zu unklar stimmt, erscheint mir widersprüchlich. Das verhindert m.W., dass die Frage abgeräumt wird, wenn sie nicht verbessert wird. Wenn der Frager zufrieden ist wird sie dann auch oft nicht verbessert.